# convert json array to single array based on id

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I want to convert an array to another array based on the `ID` and `class` properties.

I have an array:

```js
const json = [{
  "ID": 10,
  "Sum": 860,
  "class": "K",
}, {
  "ID": 10,
  "Sum": 760,
  "class": "one",
}, {
  "ID": 10,
  "Sum": 860,
  "class": "two",
}];
```

I want to create data in below format:

```
[{"ID":10,"K":860,"one":760,"two":860}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe there is more efficient solution, I have created this in 5 minutes.

```js
const input = [
{
    "ID": 10,
    "Sum": 860,
    "class": "K",
},
{
    "ID": 10,
    "Sum": 760,
    "class": "one",
},
{
    "ID": 10,
    "Sum": 860,
    "class": "two",
}];

const result = [];

input.forEach(item => {
  const exists = result.find(i => i.id === item.id);
  if (exists) {
    exists[item.class] = item.Sum;
  } else {
    item[item.class] = item.Sum;
    delete item.Sum;
    delete item.class;
    result.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(result)
```